# How promises responses are ordered in play framework when using sequence?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I am developing an application with an action which will need to do a dynamic number of HTTP requests (from 1 to 12).
I found that the best way to go is using Promises with the method "Promise.sequence" to do the calls in parallel.

I have one question regarding this method, is it guaranteed that the order of the replies respects the order of the queries?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean `Future.sequence` (I guess `Promise.sequence` is Play's Java wrapper for it), the order will be respected since it's just implemented in terms of `foldLeft`.

But let's try out! I hope you don't mind a bit of Scala.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}

object TestFutures extends App {

  val computeContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10))
  val readyContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10))

  val futures = for (i <- 1 to 10) yield {
    val f = Future { Thread.sleep(1000 * (10 - i)); i } (computeContext)
    f.onSuccess { case j => println(s"$j is ready!") } (readyContext)
    f
  }

  implicit val sequenceContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())

  Future.sequence(futures).foreach(println)

}
```

Result is

> 10 is ready!
>
> 9 is ready!
>
> 8 is ready!
>
> 7 is ready!
>
> 6 is ready!
>
> 5 is ready!
>
> 4 is ready!
>
> 3 is ready!
>
> 2 is ready!
>
> 1 is ready!
>
> Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I performed such tests too, but was not sure it was enough to conclude.